# UIWebview Shows Blurry text after rotation of device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have an `UIWebview` were i'm just loading a static text like,

```
 [[self descriptionWebView] loadHTMLString: @"<p style= 'font-size:30px''margin-left:0' align='left'>This is a sample webview</p> baseURL:nil];
 [[self descriptionWebView] setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Here i was able to zoom my **[self descriptionWebView]**, when the device is rotated i need to reset the zoom for the `UIWebView` for that i have written code in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

```
[[[self descriptionWebView] scrollView] setZoomScale:self.descriptionWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale animated:NO];
```

The Zoom level is reseted but the Text Looks BLUR. I have even done,

```
 [[self descriptionWebView].scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
 [[self descriptionWebView].scrollView setNeedsLayout];
```

But still it looks blur.

Comment: Did you try to reload the webView?

Comment: Yes i have tried to reload but same reult!!

Comment: I'm guessing this is a possible cause without testing: but when you rotate does the view containing your webview (or one of the views containing that) end up with a frame x or y position that is not a whole-number ?

Comment: If your frame has an origin that isn't a whole number, try using CGRectIntegral()

Comment: I have tried adding CGRectIntegral, but still its looks blur.!!